# Laravels Eloquent ORM: setting datatypes of the model

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

Currently I have a simple table with two rows: `id` and `key`.

Whenever I try to get my data from the database with `City::get()` the response contains `id` columns in the string format.

Is there a simple way/package how I can define the data formats for each of my columns? E.g. - `id` in this example should have been an integer.

Model:

```
<?php
class City extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'cities';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id';

}
```

Controller:

```
class CityController extends \BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        var_export(is_integer(City::get()->first()->Id));
        var_export(is_string(City::get()->first()->Id));
        die;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Comment: Is the id column an int as well?

Comment: Yes, it is a primary key that auto increments. The data type is INT.

Comment: Can you paste the model? This is weird because I have added a module for debugging and it checks data types and casts them...

Comment: Yes, sure. Just posted the model and controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every field from a record that comes out of the database is going to be a string.

This is just how many db extensions in PHP seem to work.

Ruby on Rails keeps a constant map of the schema to know that tableA.field1 is an integer, so it can convert anything to an int when it fetches the database. This obviously has some overhead to it, but it can be a useful feature. Laravel opted to not do this in the interest of performance over convenience.

You can use [accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators) to manually replicate this functionality.

Comment: Is there not some sort of package/library that works around this problem?

Comment: As far as I know, no. PHP is weakly typed so PHP doesn't care. It depends where the output is going. To output stuff to JSON I built Fractal which can help with types amongst various other things: http://fractal.thephpleague.com/

Answer (score 4):

Eloquent Models have a property `casts` that can be used to hint at the type for each model attribute.

- 5.0: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#attribute-casting
- 5.4: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

This was my case using eloquent for a legacy application locked to PHP 5.4.
For some random reason i didn't try to figure out, every attribute was retrieved as a string from the database and the default PHP casting was causing me problems.

Your code would be:

```php
<?php
class City extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'cities';
    protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
    protected $casts = [
        'Id' => 'int'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Brilliant for fields directly on a model. Sadly I could not figure out how to do this on a pivot table though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the data type in the database is an integer (INT) as well?
Else you could, maybe, convert the string to an integer. For example:

```
$num = "4.5";
$int = (int)$num;

return gettype($int); // Integer
```

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure about the datatype in the database. Perhaps Laravel has somehow indexed it incorrectly? If so - is there a way to re-run the indexation process? For a single variable the conversion would be OK, but if I have multiple tables with all sorts of rows - in my opinion this solution would just make the code look nasty.